# Nested XML parsing

Tags: php, xml

Hi guys I need help with parsing an XML with multiple nested attributes. Little part of the XML file is here http://pastebin.com/bswFcdeX
I need to parse XML and save every node to DB. I'm using Laravel. I have this, currently:

```
foreach ($lista->sport as $sport){

    foreach ($lista->sport->league as $liga){


        $mLiga = new League();
        $mLiga->liga_id = $liga->attributes()->leagueID;
        $mLiga->liga = $liga->attributes()->competition;
        $mLiga->sport_id = current($sport->attributes()->id);
        $mLiga->save();

    }

    $mSport = new Sport();
    $mSport->id = $sport->attributes()->id;
    $mSport->sport_eng = $sport->attributes()->name;
    $mSport->save();

}
```

The Sport table is populating correctly, but the League table populates all data with all Sport data, combined, making unwanted duplicates, instead of just populating data within THAT Sport node. I thought that *current($sport->attributes()->id)* will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($lista->sport as $sport){

    foreach ($sport->league as $liga){


        $mLiga = new League();
        $mLiga->liga_id = $liga->attributes()->leagueID;
        $mLiga->liga = $liga->attributes()->competition;
        $mLiga->sport_id = current($sport->attributes()->id);
        $mLiga->save();

    }

    $mSport = new Sport();
    $mSport->id = $sport->attributes()->id;
    $mSport->sport_eng = $sport->attributes()->name;
    $mSport->save();

}
```

you would iterate in the nested loop the wrong entrys. try the upper code, so you iterate al the leagues of one Sport